# SQLite automatic optimization

Tags: sqlite, optimization

I wonder: what is the state of the automatic query optimization in SQLite?
I was particularly shocked by this old question (which I found by chance, searching something else):

[SQLite table aliases effecting the performance of queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367548/sqlite-table-aliases-effecting-the-performance-of-queries)

As you can read, it is stated that that query produces a cartesian product. Which would be surely true if no query planner or optimization existed at all.
But that one seems to me a case which should trigger an automatic optimization, at the very least serializing the ANDs clauses, if nothing else (as one of the replies to that questions suggested to do manually).

My, maybe too much optimistic, understanding was that DB query optimization techniques were not so far from compiler optimization techniques (= doing automatically most of the more obvious optimization work).

But what is the really state of the things?

The question is not just to satisfy a curiosity, but because I have a C++ program which interacts with a SQLite DB and which is plenty of queries not so different from the one shown in that question and I would be quite shocked if now I discovered that I need to make manually trivial optimizations.

Thanks.

Edit: to reply more on the point to the comment below of a_horse_with_no_name, this is an example of a query from my own program:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_topic Topic, user AutoreTopic, forum_post LastPost, user AutoreLastPost  
WHERE (Topic.ForumTopic__subforum_C9_id = 1) AND
      (Topic.ForumTopic__author_C0_id = AutoreTopic.C0_id) AND
      ((LastPost.ForumPost__topic_last_post_C15_id = Topic.C15_id) AND
      (LastPost.ForumPost__author_C0_id = AutoreLastPost.C0_id)) ORDER BY
 LastPost.C16_id DESC  LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0;
```

Now, is this going to produce a cartesian product of all the 4 tables, followed then by an evaluation of the conditions, or the query planner will serialize the 4 ANDs clauses and only then do a cartesian product (using the subsets created, which should be probably more efficient)?

Comment: The query in the linked question makes no sense at all and the cartesian product that results from that is most probably not the original intention. I fail to see how (and why) a DBMS should "optimize" that

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : Just leave aside the detail of the specific query: think that it was about 4 different columns from 4 different tables. Would the optmizer just do the cartesian product of the tables or serialize the ANDs clauses?

Comment: The query in _your_ question is not a cartesian product as you are properly joining the tables (albeit with the archaic implicit joins in the where clause instead of the "modern" explicit `JOIN`  operator).

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: ok, thanks. :)

Comment: @CL. Reading the documentation, it seems that indeed there are some automatic optimization, thanks. :)